# DIY Social Dashboard

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter, instagram, instagram-api

I'd like some feedback on how doable this idea is. I'd like to have a spreadsheet that aggregates a searched hashtag or @ mention, and then lists the username who posted something with that hashtag or @ mention, as well as listing the usernames for anyone that likes or comments on the post. I'd like this to work for Instagram, Twitter, and Facebook.

Lower priority, but also of interest, would be to have another list in the spreadsheet that shows the people who are posting/liking/commenting on the specific hashtag or @ mention on *multiple* platforms (someone that does this on Instagram *and* Facebook).

Regarding API's that can grab the data needed for this from each platform, OR any existing tools that can do this...how realistic is creating this?

Thanks!

Comment: It is definitely *doable*. Question is how much effort are you willing to put into making it?

Comment: Do you know of any existing tools that accomplish getting this data? If not, I'm definitely willing to build it myself or outsource it.

Comment: @Marc try picodash.com, you can search anything Instagram

Comment: @krisrak picodash looks very cool, thanks!